# Difference between Weblogic 12c Node Manager Versions

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Today I asked myself what the differences between the two Node Manager versions are.
The documentation says:

> Java-based Node Manager provides more security than the script-based version.

But why is the Java-based version more secure?

See: [Node Manager Dokumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21050/overview.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**Determining Which Node Manager Version to Use:**

The script based Node Manager requires a much simpler security configuration than the Java version. *RSH and SSH are generally easier to configure than SSL which is the method of security used by the Java version of Node Manager*. The script version of Node Manager also required a smaller footprint than the Java version

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/server_start/nodemgr.html

Comment: I found that text in the documentation, too. But the only reason for more security is the much simpler way to configure the Java Node Manager Version?